# How to deploy a second server on port 80 (listen EADDRINUSE :::80)

Tags: node.js, http, server, centos

I'm trying to deploy a server developed with node.js for a specific url on a website.
There already is a server for covering all url on the website and I would like mine aonly answer when 

`the_website_url/my_specific_url`

is called. 
When I deploy it via ssh on the CentOS machine of the company, it's saying

`listen EADDRINUSE :::80`

How I can redirect the tcp packages only the ones asking for the specific url to my server ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  At least not without more effort than you want to spend.  You'd need to move the existing web server to a different port, and deploy some sort of reverse web proxy to look at all the requests and decide which server hand them to.